# Recursively using \@ifnextchar in itemize environment

Tags: macros, conditionals, recursion

I'm having some troubles using the `\@ifnextchar` macro recursively. My goal is to be able to call `\subitem{item1}{item2}...{itemN}` inside either an `enumerate` or `itemize` environment. This is what I have so far, but it only picks up the first argument.

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\checknextarg}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextarg}{}}
\newcommand{\gobblenextarg}[1]{ \item #1\checknextarg}
\newcommand*\@enumerate{enumerate}
\newcommand*\@itemize{itemize}
\renewcommand{\subitem}[1]{%
  \ifx\@currenvir\@enumerate
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item #1\checknextarg
    \end{enumerate}
  \else
    \ifx\@currenvir\@itemize
        \begin{itemize}
            \item #1\checknextarg
        \end{itemize}
    \fi
  \fi    
}
\makeatother
```

For example

```
\begin{enumerate}
 \item foo
 \subitem{bar}{baz}
\end{enumerate}
```

Produces

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I use a token cycle (a tool to recursively cycle through the tokens of an input stream), with the following directives:

1. If the next token is a character or a macro (i.e., control sequence), end the token cycle + end the subenumerate + restore that next token to the input stream
2. If the next token is a cat-1 group, apply `\item` to the group content
3. If the next token is a space, ignore it.

The MWE, which demonstrates the effectiveness when the `\subenumerate` occurs either in the middle of an item, between items, or at the end of an enumeration.

Here, I did not discern the itemize vs. enumerate, but just solved it for `enumerate`.  An equivalent `\subitemize` may be constructed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\Characterdirective{\tcpush{\noexpand\endtokcycraw\end{enumerate}#1}}
\Groupdirective{\item{#1}}
\Macrodirective{\tcpush{\noexpand\endtokcycraw\end{enumerate}#1}}
\Spacedirective{}
\newcommand\subenumerate{\begin{enumerate}\tokencyclexpress}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item foo1
 \subenumerate{bar}{baz}
  continue foo
 \item foo2
 \subenumerate{bar2}{baz2}
 \item foo3
 \subenumerate{bar3} {baz3}
\end{enumerate}
End of enumerate
\end{document}
```

[image]

The token cycle directives can, alternatively, be consolidated into the macro definition itself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\subenumerate{\begin{enumerate}\tokencycle
  {\tcpush{\noexpand\endtokencycle\end{enumerate}##1}}%CHARS
  {\item{##1}}%GROUPS
  {\tcpush{\noexpand\endtokencycle\end{enumerate}##1}}%MACROS
  {}%SPACES
}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item foo1
 \subenumerate{bar}{baz}
  continue foo
 \item foo2
 \subenumerate{bar2}{baz2}
 \item foo3
 \subenumerate{bar3} {baz3}
\end{enumerate}
End of enumerate
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd warn you against this idea. It breaks all known syntax for LaTeX (and you'll have problems if you want to make an index).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\check@next@arg}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\another@item}{\finish@up}}
\newcommand{\another@item}[1]{\item #1\check@next@arg}
\renewcommand{\subitem}{%
  \edef\finish@up{\noexpand\end{\@currenvir}}%
  \expandafter\begin\expandafter{\@currenvir}%
  \check@next@arg
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item foo
 \subitem{bar}{baz}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
 \item foo
 \subitem{bar}{baz}{whatever}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's your error? You absorb the first argument and when your `\checknextarg` command enters the scene, it finds `\end` as the next token.

My preference would go for explicit markup. However, here's a slightly different version that allows for choosing a different list type and uses a single argument that's split at `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\sublist}{om}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \richbai_sublist:vn { @currenvir } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \richbai_sublist:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__richbai_sublist_items_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \richbai_sublist:nn
 {
  \begin{#1}
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__richbai_sublist_items_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \item \seq_use:Nn \l__richbai_sublist_items_seq { \item }
  \end{#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \richbai_sublist:nn { v }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item foo
 \sublist{bar \\ baz}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
 \item foo
 \sublist[enumerate]{bar \\ baz \\ whatever}
 \item bar
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
 \item foo
 \sublist{bar \\ baz \\ whatever}
 \item bar
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand it's not the latex way, but making sub-items in latex is a major chore. Would you recommend a different approach that still allows the ease of use but doesn't break latex syntax?

Comment: @richbai90 I added a different version that's even easier to type in.